# Java Swing - place image in JLabel to/above second JLabel (map, player indicator)

Tags: java, swing

I have a JFrame window with GridBagLayout(). There is a JLabel with Icon - it's a map. Now I need to show another picture (player position indicator) above map.

Is it possible, how?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subclass JLabel and override the paint method.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    // paint player location on map
}
```

Handle your conversion from in game coordinates to coordinates on the map.

Comment: @trashgod Changed it. You're right, I always do `paintComponent()` myself but I must have overlooked it. Thanks for catching it.

Comment: Thank you. I have to learn how to draw with Graphics. Till now I only used ImageIcon directly with JLabel.

Comment: @Dacesilian [Java Graphics Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html) Is a good starting place, it's not difficult at all to do 2D Graphics in Java :D

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to `paintComponent()`, you might also want to look at [`OverlayLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/OverlayLayout.html), seen [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/AtestoftheOverlayLayoutmanagerallowingexperimentation.htm). For some reason it's not included in the [gallery](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html), but it may be of use.

Comment: Interesting, I'll have to play around with that sometime.

Comment: always felt that it's pretty useless - a) or can _you_ predict what the the outcome of the layout initially and when you change the alignments (digging my own grave here :-) b) it doesn't seem to be about z-ordering (as I would naively expect) or even unrelated: on rollover the button is painted on-top .. c) positioning of the layered components relative to each other (which is a requirement of the OP, as I understood it) isn't possible.

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't resist to take this question as an opportunity to play with new jdk7 api :-)

Override paintComponent definitely *is* a good solution. Nevertheless, it requires subclassing just to paint something at a given location on top of something else. The ol' way doing so would be a JLayeredPane (which is a pain to handle). The new jdk has a JLayer component which allows to do that (and a lot more) by simple decoration of the component. Here's a snippet which:

- has a label with the base image and decorates it with the default JLayer
- adds the "player" image to the layer's glassPane
- uses [Rob's DragLayout](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2011/10/23/drag-layout/) (set on the glassPane) to move the player around, bare bones ui with two sliders

Working code (just some outer boiler plate missing, you all have your templates to stick that in :)

```
  // to please Andrew :)
  JLabel fooLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(
          new URL("http://pscode.org/media/stromlo2.jpg"))));

  final JLayer<JLabel> layer = new JLayer<JLabel>(fooLabel);
  final JLabel player = new JLabel(new CursorIcon(30));
  // to please myself (never-ever use a null layout :)
  layer.getGlassPane().setLayout(new DragLayout());
  layer.getGlassPane().add(player);
  layer.getGlassPane().setVisible(true);

  final JSlider horizontal = new JSlider(0, fooLabel.getPreferredSize().width, 0);
  final JSlider vertical = new JSlider(JSlider.VERTICAL, 0, fooLabel.getPreferredSize().height, 0);
  vertical.setInverted(true);
  ChangeListener l = new ChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
        player.setLocation(horizontal.getValue(), vertical.getValue());
        layer.revalidate();
    }
  };
  horizontal.addChangeListener(l);
  vertical.addChangeListener(l);
```

Quick icon:

```
public static class CursorIcon  implements Icon {

    private int size;

    public CursorIcon(int size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y) {
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.drawLine(size/2,y,size/2,size);
        g.drawLine(x,size/2,size,size/2);
    }

    @Override
    public int getIconWidth() {
        return size;
    }

    @Override
    public int getIconHeight() {
        return size;
    }
}
```

For earlier jdk versions, the [SwingLabs subproject JXLayer](http://jxlayer.java.net) is available

Comment: @camickr nice layoutManager :-)